# How to Reference Tag in a Class using Xpath

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I'm trying to figure out how to get the link for the website by referencing the class pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-websites using xpath and selenium.

[Here is the html I'm trying to reference][1]

```py
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
website = sel.xpath("//*[@class='pv-contact-info__contact-type ci websites']")
print website
```

When I print "website" I expect there to be a list of all the things under the HTML class referenced in the code. Instead, I get an empty list.

Ideally, I would want to just be able to get the website link.

EDIT:

I'm now able to reference the specific line by doing the line below but I'm not sure how to extract the link.

```
//*[starts-with(@class,'pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-websites')]/ul/*/*/a
```

Comment: Try with this `//*[@class='pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-websites']`

Comment: How is that different from what I already have?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you are missing `-` between ci and websites.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `-` between `ci websites`.

Use the below xpath.

```
//*[@class='pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-websites']
```

**Edit 1:** updated based on conversation in the comments.

```
website = sel.xpath(" //*[starts-with(@class,'pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-websites')]/ul//a').get()
```

Comment: Ah, thank you for the fix! However, the printed output is still an empty list.

Comment: Try with `//a[starts-with(@class,'pv-contact-info__contact-link')]` and then get href attribute.

Comment: I tried the code suggested as well as 
email = sel.xpath("//a[starts-with(@class,'pv-contact-info__contact-link')]/@href").get() with no success.

Comment: Try the xpath in the browser console. Make sure the class name is correct.

Comment: It works but the problem is that there are multiple links that have that same class (contact_link).

Comment: I'm now able to reference the specific line by doing //*[starts-with(@class,'pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-websites')]/ul/*/*/a but I'm not sure how to extract the link.

Comment: just do this `website = sel.xpath(" //*[starts-with(@class,'pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-websites')]/ul//a").attrib['href']`

Comment: Sorry, Can you give one last try with `website = sel.xpath(" //*[starts-with(@class,'pv-contact-info__contact-type ci-websites')]/ul//a/@href').get()`. Make sure the xpath is pointing to the right element first.

Comment: I was able to use .get() by trying the line above without the @href. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: updated the answer based on the comments. Please accept the answer if you feel the issue is resolved, and [Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.